# Cabal build all fail on M1

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, cabal

I want to add Cardano to Express project and followed the steps in documentation: https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/installing-cardano-node/#macos. Unfortunately, “cabal build all” step failed after three hours of running.

I found a similar question on GitHub, it was advised to uninstall Libsodium, but I get an error for that as well(No such keg: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/libsodium).

Here is my terminal with the previous commands ran successfully:
[image: Terminal previous commands]

Please see the failing final message:
[image: Failing process]

Comment: Have you seen this:

https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/3506#issuecomment-1089974749

Comment: Yes, I saw that post, but libsodium uninstall failed. 
I posted a similar question on StackOverflow and provided the screenshot there. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76282227/cabal-installation-fails-on-m1

Comment: So I would think then that libsodium is not installed correctly

Comment: Welcome to the Cardano stack exchange! Please try to post your terminal output as text instead of images. Text can be found using the search or even search-engines like Google. With images this is not possible.